# getting user specific data from a webservice to populate a UITableView

Tags: iphone, web-services, uitableview, viewdidload

I am trying to populate a UITableView with data for a specific user (his projects) from a webservice, after the user as logged into the app.

for example:

```
tableData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:DICTIONARY_INITIAL_CAPACITY];
//CURRENT PROJECT
 //get the information from the server
 NSArray *currentProject = [[IHMObjectFinderServices sharedIHMObjectFinderServices]     getCurrentProjectAsArray:connectedUserId];
 if(![currentProject isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
     //put the info in a dictionnary
     NSMutableDictionary *currentProjectDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:PROJECT_DICTIONARY_CAPACITY];
     [currentProjectDictionary setObject:[currentProject objectAtIndex:INDEX_PROJECT_NAME] forKey:KEY_PROJECT_NAME];
     [currentProjectDictionary setObject:[currentProject objectAtIndex:INDEX_PROJECT_MANAGER] forKey:KEY_PROJECT_MANAGER];
     [currentProjectDictionary setObject:[currentProject objectAtIndex:INDEX_PROJECT_TAG] forKey:KEY_PROJECT_TAG];
     NSArray *activitiesForProject = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[IHMObjectFinderServices sharedIHMObjectFinderServices] getAvailableActivities:[currentProjectDictionary valueForKey:KEY_PROJECT_TAG]]];
     [currentProjectDictionary setObject:activitiesForProject forKey:KEY_PROJECT_ACTIVITIES];

     [tableData setObject:currentProjectDictionary forKey:KEY_CURRENT_PROJECT];
```

At the moment, my table loads in viewDidLoad method, so the problem is that the user is not yet connected when the table is constructed.

I have read about the reloadData method but I am not sure how to proceed to load the table only once, once the user has logged in. Could someone explain to me what is the correct procedure for this ?

Thanks for your help,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be some kind of call back method when the data for the tableView is available. Just put your reloadData in it.

```
- (void)dataIsAvailable
{
     // ... your code to set the tableData ...

     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I need to rethink the way I get the data from the server, because at this time, I'm using synchronous requests so there is no callback method for when the data is available.

Comment: Ah you should head for the [ASIHTTP framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), very easy to use. Just implement some delegate methods which are called when the request failed or succeeded. In this case the reloadData would go to the, in ASI terms `- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request` delegate method.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using this framework :-)
There is still a point where I'm struggling, it's how to fire the request once the user as logged in (I need his ID to get his data).

Even if I get the data just after the user has logged in, how do I pass it to my tableView ?

Comment: You mean, you've got two requests: login and fetch data with userID?

Comment: yes, first the user gets a screen where to put a login/password, which get send to the server. If the server allows the connection, the login screen is discarded, and he gets to the main application, where the table with the project from this user is displayed.

Comment: Alright you've got a small cascade there: After login fire the second request to fetch the data. Hide the tableview and show some nice activityindicatorview which spins. When the callback is called by ASI, stop the indicator and show the tableview after calling tableView reloadData.